# How to calculate frequencies for sequences containing NaNs?

Tags: clojure

The result of `frequencies` is wrong when used for sequencies containing `NaN`s, for example:

```
=> (frequencies [Double/NaN Double/NaN])
{NaN 1, NaN 1}
```

instead of expected `{NaN 2}`.

Furthermore, the running time deteriorates from expected/average `O(n)` to worst-case `O(n^2)`, e.g.

```
=> (def v3 (vec (repeatedly 1e3 #(Double/NaN))))
=> (def r (time (frequencies v3)))
"Elapsed time: 36.081751 msecs"
...
=> (def v3 (vec (repeatedly 1e3 #(Double/NaN))))
=> (def r (time (frequencies v3)))
"Elapsed time: 3358.490101 msecs"
...
```

i.e. 10 times so many elements need 100 times higher running time.

How can frequencies be calculated with  (expected/average) `O(n)` running time, when `NaN`s are present in the sequence?

---

As side note:

```
 => (frequencies (repeat 1e3 Double/NaN))
 {NaN 1000}
```

yields the expected result, probably because all elements in the sequence are references of the same object.

Comment: Just confirming, this is also the behavior when using the new tagged literal ##NaN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some background on `NaN` values on the JVM:  https://www.baeldung.com/java-not-a-number

---

You can solve this by encoding the `NaN` values temporarily while computing the frequencies:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core
        tupelo.test))

(defn is-NaN? [x] (.isNaN x))

(defn nan-encode
  [arg]
  (if (is-NaN? arg)
    ::nan
    arg))

(defn nan-decode
  [arg]
  (if (= ::nan arg)
    Double/NaN
    arg))

(defn freq-nan
  [coll]
  (it-> coll
    (mapv nan-encode it)
    (frequencies it)
    (map-keys it nan-decode)))

(dotest
  (let [x [1.0 2.0 2.0 Double/NaN Double/NaN Double/NaN]]
    (is= (spyx (freq-nan x)) {1.0   1,
                              2.0   2,
                              ##NaN 3})))
```

with result:

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 13
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

(freq-nan x) => {1.0 1, 2.0 2, ##NaN 3}

FAIL in (dotest-line-25) (core.clj:27)
expected: (clojure.core/= (spyx (freq-nan x)) {1.0 1, 2.0 2, ##NaN 3})
  actual: (not (clojure.core/= {1.0 1, 2.0 2, ##NaN 3} {1.0 1, 2.0 2, ##NaN 3}))
```

Note that even though it calculates & prints the correct result, the unit test still fails since `NaN` is never equal to anything, even itself.  If you want the unit test to pass, you need to leave in the placeholder `::nan` like:

```
(defn freq-nan
  [coll]
  (it-> coll
    (mapv nan-encode it)
    (frequencies it)
  ))

(dotest
  (let [x [1.0 2.0 2.0 Double/NaN Double/NaN Double/NaN]]
    (is= (spyx (freq-nan x)) {1.0   1,
                              2.0   2,
                              ::nan 3})))
```

Answer (score 4):

NaN is pretty weird in many programming languages, partly because the IEEE 754 standard for floating point numbers defines that NaN should not equal anything, not even itself.  It is the "not even itself" part that leads to most of the weird behavior you are seeing.  More here, if you are curious: https://github.com/jafingerhut/batman

The sample function below may be adaptable to your needs.  It uses :nan-kw in the returned map to indicate how many NaNs were found.  If you replace :nan-kw with ##NaN, then the returned map has the disadvantage that you cannot find the count with (get frequency-ret-value ##NaN), because of the weirdness of ##NaN.

```
(defn frequencies-maybe-nans [s]
  (let [separate-nans (group-by #(and (double? %) (Double/isNaN %)) s)
        num-nans (count (separate-nans true))]
    (merge (frequencies (separate-nans false))
           (when-not (zero? num-nans)
             {:nan-kw num-nans}))))

(def freqs (frequencies-maybe-nans [1 2 ##NaN 5 5]))
freqs
(get freqs 2)
(get freqs :nan-kw)
```

Comment: It is quite important insight, that `NaN` cannot be used as a key in the map and I need to replace it with some less strange value anyway! In this light, @Alan Thompson's solution with map + frequencies seems to be somewhat clearer / more straight forward.